# Sequentially reading a whole csv file into smaller Numpy arrays of given size

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, io

I have a .csv file several million lines long. I would like to have python sequentially read N lines at a time,  and then put them into a Numpy array to be processed.  I would like to be able to move to the next N lines without reading the file from the beginning. numpy.genfromtxt() works very well for the simple subcase of a N lines csv file.

Comment: for `csv` you can use module `csv`. it reads every row separatelly and you work with iterator. You could create generator/iterator to read more then one row sequentially. `pandas.read_csv` can read sequentiallly too - using option `chunksize`.

Comment: You can feed `genfromtxt` a list of lines. Open the file, read N lines, parse them with `gen`, repeat for the next N.

Comment: @hpaulj: You can also feed it an iterator, so `itertools.islice(f, N)` would avoid creating a throwaway list.

Comment: @Steven this looks like a nice idea! Thanks